# Google Guava Supplier Example

Tags: java, guava

Please explain the use of the interface Supplier(in Guava) with a suitable example .

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `Supplier` interface is simply an abstraction of a no-arg function that returns a value... it is a *means of getting some instance or instances of an object*. Since it is so general, it can be used as many things. Jared explained how the `Multimaps` factories utilize it as a factory for creating a new instance of a `Collection` of some type for values.

Given the simplicity of the interface, it also allows for some very powerful decoration of a `Supplier`'s behavior by wrapping it in another `Supplier` that alters its behavior somehow. Memoization is one example of that. I've used the `Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration` method myself as an easy way to make it so some data will only be read from a server at most once in a given period of time.

I'd also recommend taking a look at Guice and how the `Provider` interface is used in it. `Provider` is exactly equivalent to `Supplier` and is central to how Guice works.

- `Provider` allows users to define a custom way of creating new objects of a given class. Users can write a `get()` method which can execute whatever code is needed to create a new object, so they aren't limited to having Guice use constructors alone to create objects. Here, they are using it to define a custom *factory* for new instance of an object.
- Guice allows injection of a `Provider` of any dependency. This may return a new instance every time `get()` is called or it may always return a single instance or anything in between, depending on how the binding the `Provider` represents is scoped. This also allows for "lazy instantiation" of dependencies... the `Provider` gives a class a *means of creating an object* without needing to actually create the object ahead of time. An instance of the object does not need to be created until when, and if, `get()` is called.
- As indicated above, `Provider`s form the basis of scoping in Guice. If you take a look at the [Scope](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/Scope.html) interface, you'll notice its single method `Provider<T> scope(Key<T> key, Provider<T> unscoped)` is defined in terms of `Provider`s. This method takes *something that creates a new instance of an object* (the `Provider<T> unscoped`) and returns a `Provider<T>` based on that which applies whatever policy the scope defines, potentially returning some cached instance of the object rather than creating a new one. The default `NO_SCOPE` scope simply passes along the `unscoped` provider, meaning a new instance will be created each time. The `SINGLETON` scope caches the result of the first call to `unscoped.get()` and thereafter returns that single instance, ensuring that everything that depends on the singleton-scoped object gets a reference to that single object. Note that the `Provider` returned by the `SINGLETON` scope's `scope` method does *essentially the same thing* as the `Supplier` returned by `Suppliers.memoize` (though it's a bit more complicated).

Answer (score 14):

The main reason we included Supplier in Guava was to support the [Multimaps](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html) methods that generate arbitrary Multimaps, such as

```
public static <K,V> Multimap<K,V> newMultimap(Map<K,Collection<V>> map,
    Supplier<? extends Collection<V>> factory)
```

The Supplier creates a Collection that holds all of the values for a given key. The Multimap uses the Supplier whenever you store a key-value pair with a key that's not already in the Multimap.

Comment: Do you know about mnemonize in suppliers ?If so please give a sample for that too.

Comment: @Emil: `memoize` gets use e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636244/thread-safe-cache-of-one-object-in-java/3636791#3636791)

Answer (score 9):

It's a way to provide an indirect object. You may want to provide another object each time `Supplier.get() is` called.

For example, i have a singleton class called `SmtpMailSender`, which takes a hostname for the smtp server. However, the hostname can change at runtime, so instead of taking a `String hostname`, it takes a `Supplier<String> hostname`.

Answer (score 3):

Another example use of Supplier:

http://javawayoflife.blogspot.com/2010/06/unit-test-and-new-date.html

Answer (score 1):

See the [Suppliers](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.html) class and I guess the methods there will somehow answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Another great use of the class is decoupling - if a component only uses another to obtain a value, do not depend on the concrete implementation, but on this interface.

Anyway, there is some example code here: http://www.slideshare.net/tfnico/google-guava