# Implementing cache using Guava

Tags: java, guava

I want to implement a cache using Guava's caching mechanism.

I have a DB query which returns a map, I want to cache the entire map but let it expire after a certain amount of time.

I realize Guava caches works as a per-item bases. We provide a key, the Cache will either returns the corresponding value from the cache or get it.

Is there a way to use Guava to get everything, cache it but timeout it after a certain time period of time and get everything again.

Many thanks

Comment: `LoadingCache` is probably what you need. See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463675/how-to-automatically-refresh-cache-using-google-guava?rq=1

Comment: It almost sounds like you want a `Cache<Singleton, Map<Key, Value>>`, with just a single key.

Comment: Cache.asMap().putAll(yourMap) could be a solution if you need to cache items in your map.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an instance of `Supplier<Map<K,V>>` that fetches the entire map from the database, and then use `Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration` to cache it.

Related:

- [Google Guava Supplier Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014589/google-guava-supplier-example)
- http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Supplier.html
- http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.html