# Recursion optimisation using a "visited" set, for pure functions

Tags: java, recursion, optimization

Does Java support some form of *pure-function* annotation resulting in the compiler caching results in order to avoid re-calculation of a result.

The context is essentially traversing a graph. I'm not wanting to re-visit already-visited sections of the graph.

I can do this using a stack / visited set. However, this stack code seems like what's already going on in the call-stack - but more complicated for the code-reader. The only missing component is the `visited` set implementation.

Is this a thing? Would be cool...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the different techniques for memoization in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623754/what-are-the-different-techniques-for-memoization-in-java)

Comment: Note that other languages seem to have much better support for this than Java. Python has a `lrucache` annotation built-in that does what you want for example.

Comment: Thanks for the info / resources @Carcigenicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there's nothing built into the language. However caching values in a map is relatively easy as long as the input values are in a hashable object:

```
private final Map<Input,Output> cache = new HashMap<>();

public Output calculate(Input input) {
    return cache.computeIfAbsent(input, in -> <calc output>);
}
```

If you want to make it a LRU cache then you use `LinkedHashMap` and implement `removeEldestEntry`. Again it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Is this "Memoization" - never heard of this?

Comment: @Tobiq "memoization" basically just means caching the results of a function based on the arguments.